# C# how to save List<Panel> to file

Tags: c#, winforms, list, filestream, panels

so I've got two lists

```
public List<Panel> allPanels = new List<Panel>();
public List<Panel> displayedPanels = new List<Panel>();
```

and I'm trying to save both lists in a file (foreach list separate file). Also I want to be able to read from the files.

What I tried so far was this:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"allPanels.dat", FileMode.Create);
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(stream, allPanels);
stream.Close();
```

But it didnt quit work out because the class "Panel" isn't serializable. How can I save the two lists to a file, be able to read from the files and get the data back to the lists?

Thanks for help.

Comment: `Panel` is not serializable. What's the data that you want to save?

Comment: You cannot serialise objects that have unmanaged resources. `Panel` has an unmanaged window HANDLE value.

Comment: I've got a Class (AddGraph) with a function where the return is a Panel with a Chart inside, I'm saving those panels with charts into the list<panel>.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider saving the data relevant to the chart, rather than the whole object graph?

Comment: If it is MSChart you can either save them as image or the whole chart using  `chart.Serializer.Save(..)`

Comment: why you want to `serializable` a `panel`?, its much better to `serializable` the data that goes into that `control`(in your case, the `panel`)

Comment: ..and of course you can serilialize many or most properties needed to reconstruct the Panels. You can create a SerializablePanel class..!

Comment: So it's possible to save a List<Chart> into a file?

Comment: You are looking for saving chart image or saving chart data. You should decide based on your requirements. The image is useful when you want to use the image in an email or a document. The data is useful to let you load data again into the form and represent it using a chat control.  Saving a panel or a chart control doesn't make much sense, they are just visual representation of your data.

Comment: currently I'm still working on the UI so the chart data isn't currently of importance - I'm creating panels with charts inside of them dynamically - how am I able to keep those after closing the program and opening it again? Like I wrote I tried to write them into lists and after that into a file and try to read them again, but now that I read all the comments my idea wasn't that good.

Comment: _So it's possible to save a List<Chart> into a file?_ Not directly. You can save charts one by one or you can create a serializable class for a list of charts. It will have to make use of the chart.Serializer.

Comment: If you want to I can post a SaveableChartList. If you are interested you may want change the question title accordingly..

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and hints, I was able to rethink the situation and came up with a solution.